# Proper usage of tho in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

I would like to properly use *tho* in my sentence:

> Tho' I'm small, my effort and guts are risin'

Considering it is words spoken by an individual, I would like to know whether or not it is appropriate for me to use *tho* with an apostrophe.

Comment: *Tho* and *tho'* are both non-standard spellings for *though*. I would recommend avoiding them unless your intention is to use them in fiction as the words of some iconoclast of English orthography.

Comment: I will keep this in mind. Well, my intention is to use _tho_ in a first-person spoken dialogue and fictional story. Doesn't it in a sense convey a more curt tone or accent in speech than though?

Comment: @aitía No it does not convey a curt tone. 'Tho' is just a spelling that poets use in writing. In anything other than poetry, it looks pretentious or awfully misspelled.

Comment: If you report spoken language, and if "tho" and "though" are pronounced the same, then I say use "though".  But for written language, "tho" is used by many more people than poets...for example anyone under [a certain age] when texting.  Same people who use "u" for "you".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this non-standard spelling is that it is pronounced exactly the same as the standard form 'though'. So what are you trying to convey by mis-spelling it? Are you implying that the speaker is incapable of spelling 'though' correctly? That hardly seems reasonable. Are you trying to convey that you, as the writer, are incapable of spelling 'though' correctly? I doubt it. So...what then?

Answer (score -2):

**tho, also tho'**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/tho%27)
conj. & adv. *Informal*

> though

It can be used ... in context and informally, as in your fiction writings.